# How to have one function that can be used in multiple views in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I have `ng-if` in template HTML:

```
<div ng-if="isImage(item._file) == false">
```

So, method `isImage()` is located on current controller. How I can do common method `isImage()` that I not do duplicates on each controller and could call from view?

Comment: define it in service and then call that method

Comment: How to call from template?

Answer (score 0):

I can tell you 2 ways to do it.
The easy, but not ideal way:
In your global controller or in your app run block:

```
$rootScope.isImage = function () {
    ...
    return true;
}
```

rootScope bound variables are accessible anywhere inside of your app, so you won't need to have them in your controllers.

The correct, slightly more complicated way would be to use a custom directive.
I haven't tested this, but something along the lines of:

```
angular.module('myApp').directive("isImage", function () {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
        src: '=src'
    },
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        if (!isImage(scope.src)) { //your logic for deciding if it's an image here
            element.hide();
        }
    }
};
```

});

and in your html:

```
<is-image src="myImage"></is-image>
```